# Automatically restart server on file change

Tags: linux, web-services, command, hot-reload

I would like to run a simple-http-server (a blocking command) and have it automatically restart when specified files change on Linux.
Something like this:

`hotreload -w src/ -w index.html simple-http-server`

To restart the command whenever the directory `src` or file `index.html` change.

Is there a command like this for linux? I have only found extensions for npm and the very low level [inotify API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cargo watch`](https://github.com/passcod/cargo-watch) is actually a plugin for the Rust build tool cargo, but it can watch any files and also run shell commands:

```
cargo watch -w src/ -w index.html -s "./start_server.sh &"
```

The `start_server.sh` script should contain something like this:

```
kill $(pidof simple-http-server) # kill any running instances to free up port
simple-http-server
```

because when a server is still running in the background, the new instance won't be able to access the port.

This will run the command specified with `-s "…"` and will rerun it whenever any files or directories watched with `-w` change.